# Table view animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

For the table view i am using two arrays one for table section header and the another for table Rows if the user select on table section header i am showing the no of rows in that section my code is working fine but i want to show some animation while showing section data can any help me, i am new to i phone.  Thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UIView *backview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 30)];
    [backview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A-1.png"]]];
    cell.backgroundView = backview;
    [backview release];

    UIView *selectview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 30)];
    [selectview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A-1_h.png"]]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectview;
    [selectview release];

    UILabel *cellTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 300, 30)];
    cellTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [cellTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17]];
    [cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    cellTitle.tag=100+indexPath.row;
    cellTitle.text=[[_cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ProductGuid"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];
    [cellTitle release];

}
return cell;


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

tableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
headerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 294, 40)];
if (searching) 
{
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s10.png"]]];
    //Button
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
    button.tag = section+1;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A(2).png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    if([[cellCount objectAtIndex:section] intValue]==0) button.selected=YES;
    else button.selected=NO;


    [headerView addSubview:button];

    //Label
    UILabel *headerTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 300, 30)];
    headerTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [headerTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [headerTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17]];
    [headerTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    headerTitle.text=[[temp_details objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"InventoryLocationGuid"];   
    [headerView addSubview:headerTitle];
    [headerTitle release];
    return  headerView;
}
else {

    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s10.png"]]];

    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
    button.tag = section+1;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A(2).png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    if([[cellCount objectAtIndex:section] intValue]==0) button.selected=YES;
    else button.selected=NO;

    [headerView addSubview:button];


    UILabel *headerTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 300, 30)];
    headerTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [headerTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [headerTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17]];
    [headerTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    headerTitle.text=[[InventoryGroup objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"InventoryLocationGuid"];
    [headerView addSubview:headerTitle];
    [headerTitle release];
    if (!flag) {
        [cellCount replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag-1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];    
    }
    return  headerView;
}


-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger _index = [sender tag]-1;

if(![button2 isSelected])
    [cellCount replaceObjectAtIndex:_index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
else
    [cellCount replaceObjectAtIndex:_index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[cellArray objectAtIndex:_index]count]]];    
flag=TRUE;
//[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:_index withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can animate using this manner

The method which is used to show the rows of tapped section , will contain this method

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

similarily , The method which is used to hide rows on section tap event will contain

```
  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

method.

Comment: i know those methods but i am not inserting or deleting any row

Comment: hiding means , deleting and showing means inserting. Still if you don't want to hide , ignore the second method.

Answer (score 0):

for showing animation in table view u can use this given link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html